# Appending to a JS object that is not an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, object-literal

I have an object that looks something like this

```
{
  "_id": "DEADBEEF",
  "_rev": "2-FEEDME",
  "name": "Jimmy Strawson",
  "link": "placeholder.txt",
  "entries": {
    "Foo": 0
  }
}
```

Which is read into my javascript with a $.getJSON call.

So I have the JS object "reply" that holds all this data.

I need to append items such that "entries" becomes extended as follows:

```
{
  "_id": "DEADBEEF",
  "_rev": "2-FEEDME",
  "name": "Jimmy Strawson",
  "link": "placeholder.txt",
  "entries": {
    "Foo": 0,
    "Bar": 30,
    "Baz": 4
  }
}
```

I have tried

```
reply['entries'].push({"Bar": 0});
```

But that does not work (I presume because nothing is an array)

Can someone provide an alternative method?

Comment: `reply.entries.Bar = 0;` PS: `reply` is a JS object not a JSON.

Comment: JSON object can't look like that. It's an intrinsic object in JavaScript engines.

Comment: Thank you @zerkms!!  Now if "Bar" has to be a string, like "Bar Baz" what should I do?  Sorry. I am new to javascript!

Comment: Let's not bang on too long with all this JSON / object literal debate. We all know what OP means. OP, please read this ~ http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Uhm, `reply.entries.Bar = "string";`

Comment: I think OP means `reply.entries['Bar Baz'] = 0`

Comment: Adeneo, I am not stupid... I want to do this reply.entries."string with spaces"= 420;

thanks phil!

Comment: You shouldn't have a string with spaces as a key

Comment: thanks to all for the quick replies!! much appreciated :)

Comment: @Phil - because it's so easy to create keys without strange characters that would require brackets. I'd even go so far as to replace spaces with underscores to avoid them, however they are valid and it does work.

Comment: @Phil The terminology is important in some degree, at least the JSON tag should not be polluted with questions like this.

Comment: @Teemu don't see why you edited the question. OP had fixed it already (*ed:* ah, didn't see it had been ruined by another user)

Comment: @Phil "Removed irrelevant references to JSON", including the JSON tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reply['entries'].push({"Bar": 0})` does not work as `entries` is not of type [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) but just a plain [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object).

Use `reply['entries']["Bar"]` or `reply.entries.Bar`. See demo below:

```js
var reply = {
  "_id": "DEADBEEF",
  "_rev": "2-FEEDME",
  "name": "Jimmy Strawson",
  "link": "placeholder.txt",
  "entries": {
    "Foo": 0,
    "Bar": 30,
    "Baz": 4
  }
}
reply['entries']["Bar"] = 0;

console.log(reply);
```

Comment: thank you sir!  will accept in 8 minutes when it lets me

Comment: There is no Array [*type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values). There is a built–in Array constructor from which array instances can be created. The constructor and its instances are type [*Object*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-object-type). ;-)

Comment: Exactly! An `Array` is a special `Object`- that's what I tried to convey :)

Answer (score 5):

With *ES2017* you could use:

```js
const input = (
  { _id: 'DEADBEEF'
  , _rev: '2-FEEDME'
  , name: 'Jimmy Strawson'
  , link: 'placeholder.txt'
  , entries: (
      { Foo: 0
      }
    )
  }
)
 
const output = (
  { ...input
  , entries: (
      { ...input.entries
      , Bar: 30
      , Baz: 4
      }
    )
  }
)

console.info(JSON.stringify(output, null, 2))
```

#### Note: this will *not* mutate the original input object, but instead return a  new one (typically a good thing).

Comment: That's a great point regarding immutability of the original data. I'd make that text larger :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one more because why not ~ meet [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
let reply = {"_id":"DEADBEEF","_rev":"2-FEEDME","name":"Jimmy Strawson","link":"placeholder.txt","entries":{"Foo":0}};

Object.assign(reply.entries, {
    Bar: 30,
    Baz: 4,
    'Bar Baz': 0
});

console.log('reply =', reply);
```

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani it's probably the `let`. What browser are you running?

Comment: Yeah, must be it. My Chrome is a bit outdated. Maybe using strict mode will do the trick.

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani no, it won't. `let` is available from Chrome 41.0 which is over a year old now. In any case, this is just an example to run here on StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

it becomes an object, so just add what you want :-

```
reply.entries.Foo = 0
reply.entries.Bar = 30
reply.entries.Baz = 4
```

or `reply["entries"]["Foo"] = 0`

or `reply.entries["Foo"] = 0`

Comment: Your `Object.assign` example will remove the `Foo` property from `reply.entries`

Comment: yeah, need the spread operator, but that's not really part of js yet

Comment: Not really, you just need to operate on `reply.entries` and not `reply`

Answer (score 1):

In order to insert new entries into the **JSON** object, you could try something like this:

`object["someproperty"] = somevalue;` or `object.someproperty = somevalue;`

Say you've got the key and values in variables `someproperty` and `somevalue`, you could simply insert them as:

```
reply.entries[someproperty] = somevalue
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the alternate method:**

```
reply = {
          "_id": "DEADBEEF",
          "_rev": "2-FEEDME",
          "name": "Jimmy Strawson",
          "link": "placeholder.txt",
          "entries": {
            "Foo": 0
          }
        }
reply.entries.Bar=30;
reply.entries.Baz=4;
reply["entries"]["Bar"]=30;
reply["entries"]["Baz"]=4;
```